# How I change Project Solution Name in windows application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I made a project in Name "Project1". Now I want to changed full project named "Project2".
All code working fine. But when I create SetUp then file name Shows "Project1". How I renamed this?

Comment: Where does it show Project1?

Comment: When I published my project then generated exe file name is "Project1"

Comment: Asp.net AND winforms? Huh?

Comment: Right click your project / Application / Change AssemblyName and Default Namespace for your new name, it isn't changed by default when you rename a project

Answer (score 2):

right click the project

go to properties

go to application tab

change the assembly name

You can also change the assembly information using the button on the same page if you would like everything to tie up

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking the project and select Rename from the context menu.